# Find duplicates in two rows and apply function to all columns

Tags: r, duplicates, apply

In this example I need to check if there are any duplicates in the first column - name. There is - the first 3 rows. Now that I know this - I need to check if the column "etc2" also has duplicates in the first 3 rows. In this case, only the 2 first rows are duplicates. Then I need to take the mean of all columns in these 2 rows. After this, I move onwards with "name". Now row 5 & 6 also has the same values, then I check if the values are the same in "etc2". They are, so I need to find the mean value of all columns in these two rows.

For example, I have data that looks like this

```
dat <- read.table(text='name    value   etc1    etc2
                  A       9       20       X
                  A       10      10       X
                  A       11      1       Y
                  B       2       5       Y
                  C       40      40       Y
                  C       50      2       Y',header=TRUE)
```

And what I need to end up with is this

```
name    value   etc1    etc2
   A      9.5     15       X
   A       11      1       Y
   B        2      5       Y
   C     99.5     21       Y
```

My data set consists of a lot of rows and columns, so I am looking for a more general solution. I have tried doing an apply looking for duplicated values, and then using this number in an ifelse to get the column-sums but without much luck.

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = duplicated) 

nx <- which(apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = duplicated))[1] 

df[1, nx] # the duplicated value

ifelse(is.element(df[, 4], df[1, nx]) == TRUE, yes = colwise(mean, (df[, 1:4]), no = print("No")))
```

stuck more or less from here on

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an aggregation function, so try `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(. ~ name + etc2, dat, mean)
  name etc2 value etc1
1    A    X   9.5   15
2    A    Y  11.0    1
3    B    Y   2.0    5
4    C    Y  45.0   21
```

Other options include "data.table" and "dplyr", both of which are much more efficient than base R's `aggregate`.

```
> library(data.table)
> as.data.table(dat)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(name, etc2)]
   name etc2 value etc1
1:    A    X   9.5   15
2:    A    Y  11.0    1
3:    B    Y   2.0    5
4:    C    Y  45.0   21
> 
> library(dplyr)
> dat %>% group_by(name, etc2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: name [?]

    name   etc2 value  etc1
  (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1      A      X   9.5    15
2      A      Y  11.0     1
3      B      Y   2.0     5
4      C      Y  45.0    21
```